# jquery help opening _blank target

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've been stuck on this all day, I have a script I'm working with and it needs a bit of fine tuning. Essentially I need the following function to produce a link (website) but the target must go to a new window (_blank)

```
function build_content_string(v) {
    // build content string
    var content_string = "<div class='maps_popup'>";

    // include image
    if(v.img != '') {
        content_string += "<img class='img' src='"+v.img+"' alt='Store Image' />";
    }

    // include title & address
    content_string += "<h1>"+v.name+"</h1><h2>"+v.address+"</h2>";

    // include additional info
    if(v.telephone != '') {
        content_string += "<p class='tel'>Telephone: "+v.telephone+"</p>";
    }
    if(v.email != '') {
        content_string += "<p class='email'>Email: <a href='mailto:"+v.email+"'>"+v.email+"</a></p>";
    }
    if(v.website != '') {
        content_string += "<p class='web'>Website: <a href='"+v.website+"'>"+v.website+"</a></p>";
    }
    if(v.description != '') {
        content_string += "<p class='desc'>"+v.description+"</p>";
    }
    content_string += "</div>";

return content_string;
}
```

Let me know what you guys think...

Comment: You want the result of this function to be displayed in a new window? 
Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, the question is very unclear to me too.. you want the function to display that html into a new window, or to *return* a link..?

Comment: sorry for the unclear question, I got it working thanks to Adam, but what I was looking for was for the line

content_string += "<p class='web'>Website: <a href='"+v.website+"'>"+v.website+"</a></p>";

to produce a link that would open in a new window, replicating the target = _blank command in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those anchors to go to a new window, add a target to their definitions:

```
"<p class='web'>Website: <a target='_blank' href='"+v.website+"'>"+v.website+"</a></p>"
```

Also, it's invalid to nest elements like anchors inside of paragraphs.  Consider changing those paragraphs to spans or divs.

Comment: Thank you so much - I will make the change to divs - I'm still getting the hang of jquery - much appreciated Adam!